# Error: "Calling 'Read' when datareader is closed...."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is the code from my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample2.Models.Leave_GetDetails_Result1>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LA_StaffCode)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LA_StaffCode)
        </dd>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LA_AppNo)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    }
</div>
<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Staff_Code }) |*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

When I execute, it gives error:

```
"Calling 'Read' when datareader is closed is not a valid operation"
```

Edited:

The Controller code is below where I am calling a stored procedure:

```
using (var context = new Admin_TestEntities())
{
    var data = context.Leave_GetDetails("Recommended");
    return View(data.AsEnumerable());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a method like `ToList` in you data access layer to force the request to a database:

```
using (var context = new Admin_TestEntities())
{
    var data = context.Leave_GetDetails("Recommended").ToList();
    return View(data);
}
```

Methods like `AsEnumerable()` do not make a request to a database. The request is only made when you first access the data (in your case - in a view) or when you explicitly call a method which makes a call to the database (for example `ToList()`).

You get an error because when you try to access object in your view this is when the call to the database is actually made, but at the same time your object `context` is already disposed. To fix it you should explicitly force database query using `ToList` while the context is not yet disposed, that is in your controller method